# Cannot install wine32 in Jammy (22.04)

Tags: wine, 32-bit, 22.04

I am on Kubuntu 22.04 and have installed wine64 the usual way using apt:

```
$ wine --version
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)

$ wine64 --version
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
```

When I try to install wine32 using "apt-get install wine32", I get:

```
$ sudo apt install wine32
[sudo] password for oreo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This is impossible to fix and I can't figure out which is the offending package that I must downgrade (others who have faced this issue had to downgrade some packages).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is a recurring problem for multiple people. I have it too. Here are some other posters with the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421863/trouble-with-wine32 ;  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434526/jammy-22-04-wont-install-wine32 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434526/jammy-22-04-wont-install-wine32

Comment: I have filed an Ubuntu bug. Anyone having this problem, if they have a Launchpad account, can go to the bug and click the option "this affects me too". This will help the bug to gain some attention.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/2000832

Answer (score 5):

I had the same exact issue with Xubuntu 22.04 tonight and it drove me crazy until I figured it out.  In my case, I had a new version of `libsystemd0` for amd64 that wasn't available for i386.  There was a new version available for both amd64 and i386, but it wouldn't let me upgrade to it because of phased updates.

Running `apt-cache` to look at `libsystemd0` policy showed:

```
$ apt-cache policy libsystemd0:{amd64,i386}
libsystemd0:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.3 1 (phased 10%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libsystemd0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.3 1 (phased 10%)
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

I had version `249.11-0ubuntu3.1` installed for amd64, but it wasn't available for i386.  And version `249.11-0ubuntu3.3` was in "quarantine" due to phased upgrades and was at 10% in the above output.  And I didn't want to risk downgrading to `249.11-0ubuntu3` and break no telling what.

You have two choices.  You can wait a few more days until the upgrade becomes available.  Upgrade your system and try again to install `wine32`.

OR, do what I did and enable phased updates.  Create a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99phased-updates` file and add this line to it:

```
APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
```

Then do a `apt-get update` and try again to install `wine32`.

When you are done, you may want to change that "1" to a "0" to disable automatically getting phased updates, as it might be good to keep from breaking things on beta deployments.

Comment: Thanx bro, this is a life saver!!!

Comment: I am getting a very similar error to the OP and this fix does not seem to help. I have *no* held or pinned packages.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go after add archictecture i386 i made a lot of thing and nothing so i run sudo apt install sudo apt-get install libgd3:i386, and sudo apt-get install all dependecies with :i386 in the final with the flag pre-released updates on in the tab developer options in software and updates then sudo update and sudo apt install wine32:i386 and done my ubuntu is 22.04.02

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for me

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install wine32
```