# Trying to add i386 architecture to install Wine on 22.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, 22.04, 32-bit

I'm trying to install wine, but when it says I need wine32, I can't install it either with similar messages as trying to install i386 dependencies.

I read a post ([Cannot install wine32 in Jammy (22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410718/cannot-install-wine32-in-jammy-22-04)) where he narrowed it down to libsystemd0

from dpkg-architecture -l:

```
DEB_BUILD_ARCH=amd64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ABI=base
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=amd64
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_LIBC=gnu
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=x86_64
DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_ARCH=amd64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ABI=base
DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=amd64
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_HOST_ARCH_LIBC=gnu
DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=x86_64
DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_ARCH=amd64
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_ABI=base
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_BITS=64
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_CPU=amd64
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_LIBC=gnu
DEB_TARGET_ARCH_OS=linux
DEB_TARGET_GNU_CPU=x86_64
DEB_TARGET_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu
DEB_TARGET_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I've added the architecture:
dpkg --add-architecture i386

It shows up here:
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

but I can't install it:

```
apt-cache policy libsystemd0:{amd64,i386}
libsystemd0:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
libsystemd0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

```
apt install libsystemd0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gpgv or
                gpgv2 but it is not going to be installed or
                gpgv1 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
```

Edit: for the record, following the instructions here:
https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-winehq-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget -y
wget -O- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg] http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
```

All of those commands complete without errors.  Then

```
root@michalk-desktop:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease [8,041 B]                                                     
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                            
Get:4 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [35.1 kB]                                  
Get:5 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy/main all Packages [928 B]                                                                                   
Get:6 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages [34.9 kB]                                                                                
Hit:7 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease                                                                        
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                    
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 79.0 kB in 2s (35.1 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@michalk-desktop:~# sudo apt install winehq-stable --install-recommends  -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-stable
```

So, trying staging:

```
root@michalk-desktop:~# sudo apt install winehq-staging --install-recommends  -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 7.14~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

root@michalk-desktop:~# sudo apt install wine-staging --install-recommends  -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libasound2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 libasound2-plugins:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (>= 1.9.10+20150825) but it is not installable or
                                    libjack-0.125:i386
                           Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1-1~) but it is not installable
```

and so forth.

Edit:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libsystemd0=249.11-0ubuntu3
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This machine is a fresh install, about one week old.  The only 20.04 remnants is my home directory.  I don't pin packages, or rarely install packages with dpkg -i to prevent dependency hell.  I don't think I have broken packages, I think this is what it thinks is an "impossible situation".  It may be easier for me to do a reinstall of the OS.

Edit:  more information.

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-==========================================-=============================================-============-================================================================================
```

```
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg4-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg4-jammy.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-chromium-jammy.list:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-chromium-jammy.list:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-chromium-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-chromium-jammy.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/chromium/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list:deb https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/2.10/linux/Ubuntu_22.04/ /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg4-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg4-jammy.list.save:# deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu/ jammy main
```

Edit: more info
root@michalk-desktop:~# apt-show-versions | fgrep avail
root@michalk-desktop:~#
apt-show-versions doesn't have anything with "avail"

Comment: segustion use the officially packaged version of wine here https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: Please use https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-winehq-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/  It works perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried the official version.  Same problem with i386 dependencies.  Also tried the LinuxCapable solution.

Comment: Downgrade the version from libsystemd 64_bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libsystemd0=249.11-0ubuntu3
```

The versions from 64-bit packages and 32-bit have to match.

> ```
> apt-cache policy libsystemd0:{amd64,i386}
> libsystemd0:
>   Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4  #here to high version
>   Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.4
>   Version table:
>  *** 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 100
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>      249.11-0ubuntu3 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
> libsystemd0:i386:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3
>   Version table:
>      249.11-0ubuntu3 500
>         500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
> ```

Then try again please.

Comment: I tried this, and have unmet dependencies.  See my latest edit.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried adding the ".4", and now I get a different result:
```
sudo apt install --reinstall libsystemd0=249.11-0ubuntu3.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of libsystemd0 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

Comment: uppsie please add `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` also `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to your question @Brian Michalk

Comment: Added the dpkg and apt sources info.

Comment: The question is there you get this version before. It is not in your sources available anymore. Can you install apt-show-versions and check with `apt-show-versions | fgrep avail` how many packages are concernd.

Comment: apt-show-versions has no results with "avail".

Comment: I could never fix the problem, so I reinstalled.  The first step before adding any other packages was to enable i386, and I have not had any problems with Wine.